# Ошибка Python в библиотеке OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, numpy, opencv, pygame

Помогите пожалуйста. Столкнулся с ошибкой

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Hp1\PycharmProjects\untitled14\main.py", line 242, in convert
    ArtAscii().run()
  File "C:\Users\Hp1\PycharmProjects\untitled14\main.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.image = self.get_image()
  File "C:\Users\Hp1\PycharmProjects\untitled14\main.py", line 39, in get_image
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(transposed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-tts2sm8m\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Я разрабатываю конвертор в ASCII и другую графику. Код:

```
import pygame as pg
import numpy as np
import pygame.gfxdraw
import cv2
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter import messagebox

mode = 0
filename = ''
filename2 = ''


class ArtAscii:
    global filename, filename2
    def __init__(self, path=filename, font_size=12):
        pg.init()
        self.path = path
        self.image = self.get_image()
        self.RES = self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = self.image.shape[0], self.image.shape[1]
        self.surface = pg.display.set_mode(self.RES)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.ASCII_CHARS = ' .",:;!~+-xmo*#W&8@'
        self.ASCII_COEFF = 255 // (len(self.ASCII_CHARS) - 1)
        self.font = pg.font.SysFont('Courier', font_size, bold=True)
        self.CHAR_STEP = int(font_size * 0.6)
        self.RENDERED_ASCII_CHARS = [self.font.render(char, False, 'white') for char in self.ASCII_CHARS]

    def draw_ascii_image(self):
        char_indices = self.image // self.ASCII_COEFF
        for x in range(0, self.WIDTH, self.CHAR_STEP):
            for y in range(0, self.HEIGHT, self.CHAR_STEP):
                char_index = char_indices[x, y]
                if char_index:
                    self.surface.blit(self.RENDERED_ASCII_CHARS[char_index], (x, y))

    def get_image(self):
        self.cv2_image = cv2.imread(self.path)
        transposed_image = cv2.transpose(self.cv2_image)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(transposed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return gray_image

    def draw_cv2_image(self):
        resized_cv2_image = cv2.resize(self.cv2_image, (self.WIDTH // 2, self.HEIGHT // 2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imshow('img', resized_cv2_image)

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.fill('black')
        self.draw_ascii_image()
        self.draw_cv2_image()

    def save_image(self):
        pygame_image = pg.surfarray.array3d(self.surface)
        cv2_img = cv2.transpose(pygame_image)
        cv2.imwrite(filename2, cv2_img)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for i in pg.event.get():
                if i.type == pg.QUIT:
                    exit()
                elif i.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if i.key == pg.K_s:
                        self.save_image()
            self.draw()
            pg.display.set_caption(str(self.clock.get_fps()))
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick()


class ArtAsciiColor:
    global filename, filename2
    def __init__(self, path=filename, font_size=12, color_lvl=8):
        pg.init()
        self.path = path
        self.COLOR_LVL = color_lvl
        self.image, self.gray_image = self.get_image()
        self.RES = self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = self.image.shape[0], self.image.shape[1]
        self.surface = pg.display.set_mode(self.RES)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.ASCII_CHARS = ' ixzao*MW&8%B@$'
        self.ASCII_COEFF = 255 // (len(self.ASCII_CHARS) - 1)
        self.font = pg.font.SysFont('Courier', font_size, bold=True)
        self.CHAR_STEP = int(font_size * 0.6)
        self.PALETTE, self.COLOR_COEFF = self.create_palette()

    def draw_ascii_image(self):
        char_indices = self.gray_image // self.ASCII_COEFF
        color_indices = self.image // self.COLOR_COEFF
        for x in range(0, self.WIDTH, self.CHAR_STEP):
            for y in range(0, self.HEIGHT, self.CHAR_STEP):
                char_index = char_indices[x, y]
                if char_index:
                    char = self.ASCII_CHARS[char_index]
                    color = tuple(color_indices[x, y])
                    self.surface.blit(self.PALETTE[char][color], (x, y))

    def create_palette(self):
        colors, colors_coeff = np.linspace(0, 255, num=self.COLOR_LVL, dtype=int, retstep=True)
        color_palette = [np.array([r, g, b]) for r in colors for g in colors for b in colors]
        palette = dict.fromkeys(self.ASCII_CHARS, None)
        colors_coeff = int(colors_coeff)
        for char in palette:
            char_palette = {}
            for color in color_palette:
                color_key = tuple(color // colors_coeff)
                char_palette[color_key] = self.font.render(char, False, tuple(color))
            palette[char] = char_palette
        return palette, colors_coeff

    def get_image(self):
        self.cv2_image = cv2.imread(self.path)
        transposed_image = cv2.transpose(self.cv2_image)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(transposed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(transposed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return image, gray_image

    def draw_cv2_image(self):
        resized_cv2_image = cv2.resize(self.cv2_image, (self.WIDTH // 2, self.HEIGHT // 2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imshow('img', resized_cv2_image)

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.fill('black')
        self.draw_ascii_image()
        self.draw_cv2_image()

    def save_image(self):
        pygame_image = pg.surfarray.array3d(self.surface)
        cv2_img = cv2.transpose(pygame_image)
        cv2.imwrite(filename2, cv2_img)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for i in pg.event.get():
                if i.type == pg.QUIT:
                    exit()
                elif i.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if i.key == pg.K_s:
                        self.save_image()
            self.draw()
            pg.display.set_caption(str(self.clock.get_fps()))
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick()


class ArtPixel:
    global filename, filename2
    def __init__(self, path=filename, pixel_size=7, color_lvl=8):
        pg.init()
        self.path = path
        self.PIXEL_SIZE = pixel_size
        self.COLOR_LVL = color_lvl
        self.image = self.get_image()
        self.RES = self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = self.image.shape[0], self.image.shape[1]
        self.surface = pg.display.set_mode(self.RES)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.PALETTE, self.COLOR_COEFF = self.create_palette()

    def draw_ascii_image(self):
        color_indices = self.image // self.COLOR_COEFF
        for x in range(0, self.WIDTH, self.PIXEL_SIZE):
            for y in range(0, self.HEIGHT, self.PIXEL_SIZE):
                color_key = tuple(color_indices[x, y])
                if sum(color_key):
                    color = self.PALETTE[color_key]
                    pygame.gfxdraw.box(self.surface, (x, y, self.PIXEL_SIZE, self.PIXEL_SIZE), color)

    def create_palette(self):
        colors, colors_coeff = np.linspace(0, 255, num=self.COLOR_LVL, dtype=int, retstep=True)
        color_palette = [np.array([r, g, b]) for r in colors for g in colors for b in colors]
        palette = {}
        colors_coeff = int(colors_coeff)
        for color in color_palette:
            color_key = tuple(color // colors_coeff)
            palette[color_key] = color
        return palette, colors_coeff

    def get_image(self):
        self.cv2_image = cv2.imread(self.path)
        transposed_image = cv2.transpose(self.cv2_image)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(transposed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        return image

    def draw_cv2_image(self):
        resized_cv2_image = cv2.resize(self.cv2_image, (self.WIDTH // 2, self.HEIGHT // 2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imshow('img', resized_cv2_image)

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.fill('black')
        self.draw_ascii_image()
        self.draw_cv2_image()

    def save_image(self):
        pygame_image = pg.surfarray.array3d(self.surface)
        cv2_img = cv2.transpose(pygame_image)
        cv2.imwrite(filename2, cv2_img)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for i in pg.event.get():
                if i.type == pg.QUIT:
                    exit()
                elif i.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if i.key == pg.K_s:
                        self.save_image()
            self.draw()
            pg.display.set_caption(str(self.clock.get_fps()))
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick()


def image():
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Картинки", "*.jpg *.png")])
    lbl.configure(text=filename)

def image_save():
    global filename2
    filename2 = askdirectory()
    lbl1.configure(text=filename2)

def mode_rad1():
    global mode
    mode = 1

def mode_rad2():
    global mode
    mode = 2

def mode_rad3():
    global mode
    mode = 3

def convert():
    if not filename:
        messagebox.showerror('ОШИБКА 0000', 'Выбери картинку')
    elif not filename2:
        messagebox.showerror('ОШИБКА 0000', 'Выбери куда сохранить')
    elif mode == 0:
        messagebox.showerror('ОШИБКА 0000', 'Выбери режим')
    else:
        if mode == 1:
            ArtAscii().run()
        if mode == 2:
            ArtAsciiColor().run()
        if mode == 3:
            ArtPixel().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Конвертор")
    window.geometry('250x150')
    window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    lbl = Label(window, text="Выберите картинку")
    lbl.place(x=60, y=15)
    btn1 = Button(text="...", padx="4", pady="3", font="10", command=image)
    btn1.place(x=200, y=10)
    lbl1 = Label(window, text="Куда сохранить при нажатии S")
    lbl1.place(x=25, y=50)
    btn2 = Button(text="...", padx="4", pady="3", font="10", command=image_save)
    btn2.place(x=200, y=45)
    rad1 = Radiobutton(window, text='ASCII', value=1, command=mode_rad1)
    rad2 = Radiobutton(window, text='ASCII COLOR', value=2, command=mode_rad2)
    rad3 = Radiobutton(window, text='PIXEL ART', value=3, command=mode_rad3)
    rad1.place(x=10, y=80)
    rad2.place(x=60, y=80)
    rad3.place(x=155, y=80)
    btn3 = Button(text="КОНВЕРТИРОВАТЬ", padx="4", pady="3", font="10", command=convert)
    btn3.place(x=40, y=110)
    window.mainloop()
```

Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: Подсказка прямо в тексте ошибки: `!_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'`

Comment: Посмотрите отладчиком, чему у Вас равно `transposed_image` в методе `get_image`. Есть подозрение, что у Вас там получается пустой объект, а значит, скорее всего, на тот момент `self.cv2_image` ещё не было инициализировано.

Comment: Я понял в чем ошибка когда я через tkinter получал картинку то слеши были такими / а что бы OpenCV нашел картинку слеши должны быть такими \

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем ошибка когда я через tkinter получал картинку то слеши были такими / а что бы OpenCV нашел картинку слеши должны быть такими \